# How to make HTML5 draggable objects over canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, draggable

I just started learning html5 and I am trying to create a battleship interface with draggable ships. I need help making my dragging methods work. I am purposely not using a library because I need make the ships draggable over another canvas interface (the battleship board), which I could not figure out how to do with the Kinetic library. I feel like I am close, but I cannot figure out the last bit. The ships should be smoothly dragged but they seem to snap to the location of the mouse when clicked...

Here is my clode:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Canvas Drag and Drop Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>

            <div align=center>
                <canvas id="canvas" width="550" height="550">
                    This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
                </canvas>
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                var canvas;
                var ctx;
                var x = 75;
                var y = 50;
                var WIDTH = 550;
                var HEIGHT = 550;
                var dragok = false;
                var ships = [];
                var ship;
                var shipFill = "#FF0000";
                //Definitions
                //Draggable Carrier
                var caRectX = 100;
                var caRectY = 50;
                var caRectHeight = 50;
                var caRectWidth = 5 * 50;
                var carrier = {
                    x : caRectX,
                    y : caRectY,
                    width : caRectWidth,
                    height : caRectHeight,
                    fill : shipFill,
                    dragging : false,
                    offsetX : 0,
                    offsetY : 0,

                };
                ships.push(carrier);
                //Draggable Battleship
                var bsRectX = 100;
                var bsRectY = 150;
                var bsRectHeight = 50;
                var bsRectWidth = 4 * 50;

                var battleship = {
                    x : bsRectX,
                    y : bsRectY,
                    width : bsRectWidth,
                    height : bsRectHeight,
                    fill : shipFill,
                    dragging : false,
                    offsetX : 0,
                    offsetY : 0,

                };
                ships.push(battleship);

                //Draggable Patrolboat
                var pbRectX = 100;
                var pbRectY = 250;
                var pbRectHeight = 50;
                var pbRectWidth = 2 * 50;

                var patrolboat = {
                    x : pbRectX,
                    y : pbRectY,
                    width : pbRectWidth,
                    height : pbRectHeight,
                    fill : shipFill,
                    dragging : false,
                    offsetX : 0,
                    offsetY : 0,

                };
                ships.push(patrolboat);

                //Draggable Submarine
                var suRectX = 100;
                var suRectY = 350;
                var suRectHeight = 50;
                var suRectWidth = 3 * 50;

                var submarine = {
                    x : suRectX,
                    y : suRectY,
                    width : suRectWidth,
                    height : suRectHeight,
                    fill : shipFill,
                    dragging : false,
                    offsetX : 0,
                    offsetY : 0,

                };
                ships.push(submarine);

                //Draggable destroyer
                var deRectX = 100;
                var deRectY = 450;
                var deRectHeight = 50;
                var deRectWidth = 3 * 50;

                var destroyer = {
                    x : deRectX,
                    y : deRectY,
                    width : deRectWidth,
                    height : deRectHeight,
                    dragging : false,
                    fill : shipFill
                };
                ships.push(destroyer)

                function rect(x, y, w, h) {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.rect(x, y, w, h);
                    ctx.closePath();
                    ctx.fill();
                }

                function clear() {
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                }

                function init() {
                    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    return setInterval(draw, 10);
                }

                function draw() {
                    clear();
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#FAF7F8";
                    rect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#444444";
                    for (var i = 0; i < ships.length; i++) {
                        rect(ships[i].x, ships[i].y, ships[i].width, ships[i].height);
                    }
                }

                function myMove(e) {
                    if (ship.dragging) {
                        ship.x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                        ship.y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
                        draw()
                    }
                }

                function myDown(e) {
                    ship = getClickedShip(e.pageX,e.pageY);
                    if (ship!=null) {
                        ship.x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                        ship.y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
                        ship.dragging = true;
                        canvas.onmousemove = myMove();
                    }
                }

                function myUp() {
                    ship.dragging = false;
                    canvas.onmousemove = null;
                }

                function getClickedShip(sx,sy){
                    for (var i = 0; i < ships.length; i++){
                        if(sx > (ships[i].x )+ canvas.offsetLeft && sx < (ships[i].x+ships[i].width+ canvas.offsetLeft) && sy > (ships[i].y + canvas.offsetTop) && sy < (ships[i].y+ships[i].height))
                            return ships[i];
                    }
                }
                init();
                canvas.onmousedown = myDown;
                canvas.onmouseup = myUp;

            </script>

        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 11):

**This is the procedure for making an html shape draggable**

Note that this has been answered before on SO (many times!)

But this answer illustrates the new context.isPointInPath method to hit-test whether a point is inside an html canvas path.

Hopefully, this new hit-testing method will be new & useful to the OP and others  :)

**Here's the general procedure for dragging shapes in html canvas:**

On mouseDown:

- save this mouseX position in a variable (lastX)
- save this mouseY position in a variable (lastY)
- set the mouseIsDown flag to true

On mouseUp

- set the mouseIsDown flag to false

On mouseMove

- Hit-test each ship to see if it should be dragged.
- If the lastX/lastY was inside a ship, that ship is being dragged
- Move dragging ships by the distance the mouse has just moved

**MouseDown handler code:**

```
function handleMouseDown(e){

  // get the current mouse position relative to the canvas

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // save this last mouseX/mouseY

  lastX=mouseX;
  lastY=mouseY;

  // set the mouseIsDown flag

  mouseIsDown=true;
}
```

**MouseUp handler code:**

```
function handleMouseUp(e){

  // clear the mouseIsDown flag

  mouseIsDown=false;
}
```

**MouseMove handler code:**

This code illustrates using `context.isPointInPath` to hit-test an html canvas path

The procedure to do that is:

- define a path (but not draw it -- no fill, no stroke)
- use `context.isPointInPath(x,y)` to test if x,y are inside the path defined above.

Here's the mouseMove handler using context.isPointInPath

```
function handleMouseMove(e){

  // if the mouseIsDown flag is’nt set, no work to do

  if(!mouseIsDown){ return; }
  // get mouseX/mouseY

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // for each ship in the ships array
  // use context.isPointInPath to test if it’s being dragged

  for(var i=0;i<ships.length;i++){
      var ship=ships[i];
      drawShip(ship);
      if(ctx.isPointInPath(lastX,lastY)){ 

          // if this ship’s being dragged, 
          // move it by the change in mouse position from lastXY to currentXY

          ship.x+=(mouseX-lastX);
          ship.y+=(mouseY-lastY);
          ship.right=ship.x+ship.width;
          ship.bottom=ship.y+ship.height;
      }
  }

  // update the lastXY to the current mouse position
  lastX=mouseX;
  lastY=mouseY;

  // draw all ships in their new positions
  drawAllShips();
}
```

Note about enhancing performance:

- In production, you'll want to have the mouseMove just save the mouse positions.
- Then have another procedure retrieve those saved positions and do hit-testing/redrawing.
- That other procedure will probably be inside a timed loop like requestAnimationFrame.

Here’s code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/sEBAC/

```js
$(function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.strokeStyle = "lightgray";
  var canvasOffset = $("#canvas").offset();
  var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
  var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
  var mouseIsDown = false;
  var lastX = 0;
  var lastY = 0;
  var ships = [];

  // make some ship
  makeShip(20, 30, 50, 25, "skyblue");
  makeShip(20, 100, 30, 25, "skyblue");
  makeShip(20, 170, 50, 25, "salmon");
  makeShip(20, 240, 30, 25, "salmon");

  function makeShip(x, y, width, height, fill) {
    var ship = {
      x: x,
      y: y,
      width: width,
      height: height,
      right: x + width,
      bottom: y + height,
      fill: fill
    }
    ships.push(ship);
    return (ship);
  }

  drawAllShips();

  function drawAllShips() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (var i = 0; i < ships.length; i++) {
      var ship = ships[i]
      drawShip(ship);
      ctx.fillStyle = ship.fill;
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  }

  function drawShip(ship) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(ship.x, ship.y);
    ctx.lineTo(ship.right, ship.y);
    ctx.lineTo(ship.right + 10, ship.y + ship.height / 2);
    ctx.lineTo(ship.right, ship.bottom);
    ctx.lineTo(ship.x, ship.bottom);
    ctx.closePath();
  }

  function handleMouseDown(e) {
    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

    // mousedown stuff here
    lastX = mouseX;
    lastY = mouseY;
    mouseIsDown = true;

  }

  function handleMouseUp(e) {
    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

    // mouseup stuff here
    mouseIsDown = false;
  }

  function handleMouseMove(e) {
    if (!mouseIsDown) {
      return;
    }

    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

    // mousemove stuff here
    for (var i = 0; i < ships.length; i++) {
      var ship = ships[i];
      drawShip(ship);
      if (ctx.isPointInPath(lastX, lastY)) {
        ship.x += (mouseX - lastX);
        ship.y += (mouseY - lastY);
        ship.right = ship.x + ship.width;
        ship.bottom = ship.y + ship.height;
      }
    }
    lastX = mouseX;
    lastY = mouseY;
    drawAllShips();
  }

  $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e) {
    handleMouseDown(e);
  });
  $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e) {
    handleMouseMove(e);
  });
  $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e) {
    handleMouseUp(e);
  });
}); // end $(function(){});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Can we have the same demo working in case we want to use images ...multiple images in canvas dragable.

Comment: Use `ctx.drawImage` instead of 'ctx.fill and ctx.stroke' in drawAllShips. The image will display and the path still provides the hit region used in `isPointInPath`.  I have confidence that you can make the necessary adjustments. Cheers!

Comment: that worked well thanks, apart from this actually i have some other issues as well regarding canvas and all [wont be possible to share here]..and i want advice from someone like you [perfect]. Do you consult outside stack overflow as well...would be great and thankful, if you can give some of your time, if possible.